# Can any one explain how exactly this function works? I mean what is $context as map:map, $params as map:map

Tags: marklogic

I came across the following function, tried to understand but could not

```
declare function ext:get(
  $context as map:map,
  $params  as map:map
) as document-node()*
{
  (:here is code for logic:)
};
```

need more elaboration on what it does? ($context as map:map,
  $params  as map:map)

Comment: The only thing we can tell you from this is that you need to pass in two map objects and the function will return a document-node...where did you come across this? What are you wanting it to do?

Comment: Tyler gave you some good information. But it is better if people do not have to guess/infer things.  Elaborating on your question with more context of where and how you found the function example will further help others help you - and more complete questions can be good for others to learn form as well.

Comment: Useful reading: [How to ask a good question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- with those guidelines, we'll be able to give you more helpful answers.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a rest api extension for a GET request. You can read more about them here https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions.

If this is a rest api extension, then the `$params` map will be a list of querystring parameters that start with `rs:`.

The `(:here is code for logic :)` comment is the section where you need to put some code to handle the GET request, or show us what the actual code is.

All that it is currently doing right now is returning an empty sequence.